# Unable to comple GWT-RPC project

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt-rpc

I have followed a tutorial about how to create and deploy GWT-RPC project in eclipse.

"https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/create"

Everything went well. But iam struggling at one point, after compilation, i need to put the following url to the browser.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/test.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
```

Now my question is, how can i avoid this "?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997". I know, for developement mode, we need this. So how can we compile and execute the html files without that append?

Do i need to install the gwt sdk and compile eclipse project in other way? Please help me. I need a step by step procedure to do that. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes.You need to have a `GWT SDK`

You can download it [from here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/gettingstarted) .

After that you have to [compile your project](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/gwt_compile).

After that you can simply run your GWT project  without `?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997`